# A trivial fact about analytic functions

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analyticity

In the book that I'm reading they said that this fact is trivial , but I'm not completely sure about something and I prefer to confirm it.
It's about a lot of equivalences, but I have question about two.

Let $f$ be a function defined on a domain $D \subset {\Bbb C}$. Assume that $f$ has a power series expansion at each point of $D$, and let $\zeta  \in D$. Then the following are equivalent:

$\quad$ i) $f^{(n)} (\zeta) = 0,\;\text{ for }\;n = 0,1,2\ldots$

$\quad$ ii) $f \equiv 0$ in a neighborhood of $\zeta$

I know how to prove that i) implies ii); I want to see the other side of the proof. I think that I must use the fact that I can write $f$ locally in the form 
$$f(z) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n (z - \zeta)^n  = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(\zeta)}
{n!} (z - \zeta)^n $$
and then by the assumption we have : 
$$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(\zeta)}{n!}(z - \zeta)^n   = 0$$
But now I don't know what can I do, because the sum could be zero, because the sum has some positive terms, and other negative terms, and because this the sum it's zero. I don't know how to finish

Remark: I know that there are other equivalences, even one of them asserts that $f$ vanishes not only on a neighborhood,but in the whole domain $D$, but I want to see for the moment only this two equivalence. Thanks =)!

Comment: But ii) to i) is trivial, since $f \equiv 0$ means $f(z) = 0, \forall z \in D$, thus $f^{(n)}(z) =0, \forall z\in D$.

Comment: @Sasha: May I ask why you wanted to preserve the OP's grammar? Are msh210 and I misinterpreting what was intended? I generally feel that improving grammar in posts is both helpful to the OP and also improves readability for future readers.

Comment: @ZevChonoles It may be because grammar is not my strongest point, sorry.

Comment: @Zev: Given how close in time the edits of Sasha and msh210 were (within a second), a reasonable guess is that Sasha was working with the original question and merely did not change the grammar, but since the edit was posted (barely) afterward it undid msh210's improvements.

Comment: @Jonas: Ah, I agree that is most likely. Sorry for the confusion, Sasha :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $f\equiv 0$ on a neighborhood $U$ of $\zeta$.  The derivative of the zero function (or any other constant function) is the zero function, so $f'\equiv 0$ on $U$.  Similarly, $f''\equiv 0$ on $U$, $f'''\equiv 0$ on $U$, etc.  If $f^{(k)}\equiv 0$ on $U$, then in particular $f^{(k)}(\zeta)=0$.

Comment: @August: You're welcome.  I was looking for an easy problem when I opened the question.  It was truth in advertising.